# Shopify Slate won't build, zip or start?

Tags: shopify, slate

Trying to get running with Shopify's Slate, it installs a new theme without errors but then we I navigate into the theme and try to run slate start or slate zip, I get this error:

```
.../node_modules/@shopify/theme-lint/index.js:12
module.exports.runAll = function(path, reporter = new Reporter()) {
                                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

There is some more error code after that, but it looks like the error is when theme-link is trying to create a new reporter? Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Did you update your node.js to the latest version?

Comment: Updating via the command line didn't fix it, but re-downloading and installing the .dmg fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating Node [and npm] should fix this problem.

Slate requires Node 6.x [Slate Getting started](https://shopify.github.io/slate/#getting-started)